# How can I insert a golang map into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a json object sent from a mobile application, looks like this:

```
{
    "product_id": "0123456789",
    "name": "PRODUCT_NAME",
    "manufacturer": "PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER",
    "image_url": "IMAGE_URL",
    "additional_info": "",
    "store_id": "STORE_ID",
    "store_name": "STORE_NAME",
    "owner_id": "OWNER_ID",
    "quantities": {
        "1000": 10.0,
        "1500": 12.0,
    }
}
```

The key value in `quantities` is a for example, can be grams, and the value is a representes a price.
So for example, 1000 grams of rice will cost 10$, and 1500 grams of rice will cost 12.0$ (as a sale or something)

I have a Model Object in my `Go` code, that has the `quantities` filed as `map[int]float32`
I'm trying to find a way to insert this map into a `PostgreSQL` database I have, but can't figure out how.

This is my `Go` Model:

```
type Product struct {
    ID             string          
    UUID           string          
    Name           string         
    Manufacturer   string         
    ImageURL       string         
    AdditionalInfo string          
    StoreID        string         
    StoreName      string          
    OwnerID        string          
    Quantities     map[int]float32
}
```

I read about `JSONB` but won't it return a `json` when I retrieve the data? I need it to return a `map[int]float32` and not `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [driver.Valuer](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) and [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface for save as JSONB

The `driver.Valuer` interface, such that it marshals the object into a JSON byte slice that can be understood by the database.

The `sql.Scanner` interface, such that it unmarshals a JSON byte slice from the database into the struct fields.

And for json Marshal you need to convert `map[int]float32` into `map[string]float32`

```
type cusjsonb map[int]float32

// Returns the JSON-encoded representation
func (a cusjsonb) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // Convert to map[string]float32 from map[int]float32 
    x := make(map[string]float32)
    for k, v := range a {
       x[strconv.FormatInt(int64(k), 10)] = v
    }
    // Marshal into json 
    return json.Marshal(x)
}

// Decodes a JSON-encoded value
func (a *cusjsonb) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    // Unmarshal from json to map[string]float32
    x := make(map[string]float32)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &x); err != nil {
       return err
    }
    // Convert to map[int]float32 from  map[string]float32
    *a = make(cusjsonb, len(x))
    for k, v := range x {
      if ki, err := strconv.ParseInt(k, 10, 32); err != nil {
         return err
      } else {
         (*a)[int(ki)] = v
      }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!